# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when doing Parse.initialize(this

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have  a lot of users reporting this crash to the play console. I tested it and it only appears sometimes. The crash occurs in this exact line that I have in the ParseApplication class, which extends the Application class and which should be called before everything else no?

This is the line where it crashes:

```
 Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

This is the crash

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.hour.chat.ParseApplication: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4411)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.LinkedList$LinkIterator.next(LinkedList.java:124)
at com.parse.ParseObject.mergeREST(ParseObject.java:928)
at com.parse.ParseUser.mergeREST(ParseUser.java:285)
at com.parse.OfflineStore$13$2.then(OfflineStore.java:765)
at com.parse.OfflineStore$13$2.then(OfflineStore.java:762)
at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:381)
at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:373)
at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
at com.parse.Task.onSuccess(Task.java:373)
at com.parse.Task.onSuccess(Task.java:393)
at com.parse.OfflineStore$13.then(OfflineStore.java:762)
at com.parse.OfflineStore$13.then(OfflineStore.java:721)
at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:364)
at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:410)
at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:402)
at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: what does "Parse.initialize()" do ?

Comment: @Rocel Same issue i have with parse library for some device like Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (T30g).

Comment: @Marius Do you found solution of this crash ?

Comment: Can you post the sample code of it? From how you declared the parse until how you used it. Thanks

Comment: By any chance you are concurrently calling this method ?

Comment: which version of parse SDK used?

Comment: One suggestion is delete the app totally from your device or emulator.This question still exists in Parse blog. Also check that you use the updated version of Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Since this thread is 4 months old lets update some stuff first;

1)Update to the lastest SDK you can do this at [Parse](https://parse.com/docs)

2) Make sure you have correctly initialized your keys at Application level once you have the SDK in your project like this:

```
public class YourAppName extends Application {
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

     Parse.initialize(this, "KEY_1", "KEY_2);

    }

}
```

3)Make sure you have this defined in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<application
        android:name=".YourAppName" <!--This is the important part-->
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">

...
```

Hope it resolves your problem.